# replacing jruby script path with some other abstraction notion other than file paths

Tags: jruby

I am just guessing but would like some commentary about how to set my own ruby script loader rather than just letting the runtime take file paths.

I have not tried to load scripts, but from reading it would appear the "script path" that is searched is ...

```
ScriptingContainer {

   /**
 * Changes a list of load paths Ruby scripts/libraries. The default value
 * is an empty array. If no paths is given, the list is created from
 * java.class.path System property. This value can be set by
 * org.jruby.embed.class.path System property, also.
 * Call this method before you use put/get, runScriptlet, and parse methods so that
 * the given paths will be used.
 *
 * @since JRuby 1.5.0.
 *
 * @param paths a new list of load paths.
 */
public void setLoadPaths(List<String> paths) {
    provider.getRubyInstanceConfig().setLoadPaths(paths);
}
}
```

My understanding is the runtime expects file paths, i would like the ability to load scripts from my own provider such as a Apache commons Virtual FileSystem.